# Program To Check whether the string is Palindrome or not?

Tags: java

this is the code written by me to check whether it is palindrome or not:

```
class Solution {
public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
String trimedStr=s.replace(" ","").replace(",", "")
.replace(":", "").toLowerCase();

        String emtStr="";
        for(int i=trimedStr.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
           String charStr=String.valueOf(trimedStr.charAt(i));
           emtStr+=charStr;
        }
    
        if(emtStr==trimedStr){
          return true;
        }else{
          return
        }
    }      

}
```

I tried Conditionals, but In the case of Above string the Program is showing false o/p.

Comment: you can't compare String values with ==, use .equals()... for reference you may read eg. this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-compare-strings

Comment: actually, you can, but you would be comparing their references, not their values.

Comment: also, welcome to SO and please refer the guide on how to ask good question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask... Currently you are actually not asking anything, only presenting your problem which is not a good practice. But in this too, practice makes you better =)

Comment: BTW code does not need `charStr` - string concatenation does the conversion - `emtStr += trimedStr.charAt(i)`  ((actually using `char` can fail if the input string contains surrogate characters - in this case better use code points))

Comment: for future reference, just put something like: return emtString.equals(trimedStr); instead of what you have now. What you posted won't compile, let alone run.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `==` to compare Strings, you should be using `a.equals(b)` to compare Strings (as Strings are objects)

`==` on objects tests if two objects are identical, not if they represent the same idea. You are building up a new String by reversing the old one, so you are getting a *new* String-object.

`equals` tests if two objects represent the same value, it is defined in the String-class and knows about the characters that make up the String.

Comment: it's not "most likely" he's getting a new String. That's a certainty.

Comment: @Stultuske I would guess that is how it is implemented, but I don't think the JLS mandates that behaviour. I did remove the 'most likely' because potential optimizations enabled by immutability are irrelevant to the problem of OP.

Comment: String are immutable, hence two Strings with different values can't possibly be the same object

Comment: @Stultuske That is true. But two Strings representing the same value may or may not be identical objects. Reusing instances of immutable classes is possible in principle. I can't find a java-String example, but `Integer.valueOf("1") == Integer.valueOf("01")` returns true on my machine, while `Integer.valueOf("99999") == Integer.valueOf("99999")` returns false, because the small number is cached and the big number is not.